# How to install PrimeNG or KendoUI style library in angular microfrontend projects with Single-spa framework?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, primeng, micro-frontend, single-spa

I have been trying to install the **KendoUI** and **PrimeNG** libraries in microfrontends created with the **Single-SPA** library of Angular type, but I have not succeeded.

They work on single angular projects but under the **single-spa** framework going to the container url they don't, I think it has to do with **webpack** my problem but I'm not sure.

**Is there any adjustment that the single-spa wrapper project needs to do?**
**Does it have to do with webpack? If so, how could I resolve it?**

Any help will be welcome, I appreciate your time and response!

In a test that I did initially creating an Angular project before installing the single-spa framework, if I managed to install the libraries correctly and it was reflected in the design, but after configuring single-spa and associating them with the container project, the design of the bookstores was lost.

With **kendoUI** I install the library components via npm, then I check in the `angular.json` styles that the references to the library are there and I do some tests, the angular project as such if the components work for me but with the framework no:

- `npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-buttons`

```
"styles": [
{
    "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css"
},
    "src/styles.scss"
],
```

I also tried importing in `main.ts` the reference to the libraries

```
import '@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css';
import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';
```

With **PrimeNG** I have generally done the same as with KendoUI, I installed according to its documentation, the library via npm and I did the step by step but the library is not reflected in the design using single-spa.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the style in the main component style of the module.

In my application i have the HomeComponent and in the home.component.scss i import primeNG in this way.

```
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "../../assets//custom-theme-primeng.css";
```

That's because with webpack, maybe you are sharing only a specific module and not the main module that import styles.scss and main.ts too